# Change Picture with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, database

I want change background picture(a div) with javascript that I will take from database.
Picture is embedded in CSS.
I want to use JQuery.

CSS

```
.home_div { 
width: 958px; 
height: 350px; 
margin-bottom: 12px; 
background: url(../images/bg_home_div.png)
}
```

No JScript. But I use Jquery on other part of website.

Comment: Is the picture specified as a 'background-url' in css or its loaded as a BLOB from DB? please clarify.

Comment: Post your CSS, HTML and any JS you have so far.

Comment: Don't store JavaScript in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change easily with javascript.

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var image_url = "whatever comes from database";
            $('#image_div').css("background-image", "url('" + image_url + "')");

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: This code requires jQuery, which wasn't mentioned in the tags, the question or even this answer.

Answer (score 1):

using jquery, you can:

```
$('body').css('background-image', 'images/myimage.jpg');
```

Comment: This code requires jQuery, which wasn't mentioned in the tags, the question or even this answer.

Comment: this will change background picture?

Comment: this will change the background image on the body tag.  You can change the jquery selector $('body') to match whichever element you like.

Comment: i updated question andy. you are right. everybody use jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

With javascript

```
var newimage = "your image link";
document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.backgroundImage = 'url(newimage)'
```